# How to solve Google AppEngine PHP redirect loop (app.yaml issue)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I have so much trouble trying to find a way to migrate my php application/script to google's appengine. I think it all stems to app.yaml.

When I access localhost:9080 it goes to redirect look like the follow:

```
http://localhost:9080/index.php/admin/index.php/admin/index.php/admin/index.php/admin/index.php/admin/index.php/admin/index.php/admin/index.php/admin/index.php/admin/index.php/admin/index.php/admin/index.php/admin/index.php/admin/index.php/admin/index.php/admin/index.php/admin/index.php/admin/index.php/admin/index.php/admin/index.php/admin/index.php/admin/login
```

Whats the problem, how can I solve this ? I tried the examples like wordpress it all works but not much explaining goes to how app.yaml is derived. Especially, if we take a phpscript, how can we easily migrate to google appengine, a migration path guide/tutorial would be helpful.

anyway, here's my app.yaml

```
application: phptestapp
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
static_files: favicon.ico
upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_Script_handlers) is the link to configuring script handlers in app.yaml - LMK what's not clear about this documentation.

Without knowing your app it's hard to know what your app.yaml should look like.

I am guessing you're script index.php is redirecting to a script at admin/index.php, but you don't have a handler for that so. Perhaps your app.yaml needs to be

```
handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: (.+).php
  script: \1.php

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

So that if you have any url that specifies an exact script file, it will execute that script - like I said I'm guessing what your app should do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for the delay replying. This PHP script is based on codeigniter. I manage to get this codeigniter example working https://github.com/edwardmp/CodeIgniter-AppEngine/blob/master/app.yaml but not on my script. It is still giving the same redirect loop and i think it might be from the routes.php configured to be $route['default_controller'] = "admin/home"; Any help would be appreciated, i still think something should be matched in app.yaml to make it work. Thanks

Comment: i think its supposed to link to this url http://localhost:9080/index.php/admin/login

Answer (score 2):

Fwiw I just ran into something similar, trying to get a test WordPress instance up and running on App Engine.

Visiting `http://localhost:10080` eventually landed here — `http://localhost:10080/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php` — with the redirect loop error.

But going here directly — `http://localhost:10080/wp-admin/install.php` — worked fine.